# How to add a column which contains info aggregated over rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
# Create a dataframe
   raw_data = {'trial_num': ['1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3'], 
               'area': ['first', 'second', 'first', 'second','first','second'],
               'counts': [10, 25, 36, 2, 70, 10]}

   df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['trial_num', 'area', 'counts'])

  trial_num   area     count
0         1   first     10
1         1  second     25
2         2   first     36
3         2  second      2
4         3   first     70
5         3  second     10
```

I want to add a new column 'proportion' that expresses each count as a proportion of total per 'area'. Like this:

```
       trial_num  area     count  total_count proportion
    0         1   first     10       35    0.2857142857142857
    1         1  second     25       35    0.7142857142857143
    2         2   first     36       38    0.9473684210526315
    3         2  second      2       38    0.05263157894736842
    4         3   first     70       80    0.875
    5         3  second     10       80    0.125
```

I have only got this far:

```
df.counts.groupby(df.trial_num).sum()

trial_num
1    35
2    38
3    80
```

Is there an efficient way to do this without breaking the dataframe? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can divide by [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html) by `Series` created by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with same size as original `df`:

```
df['proportion'] = df['counts'].div(df.groupby(['trial_num'])['counts'].transform('sum'))
```

Alternative by [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
s = df.groupby(['trial_num'])['counts'].sum()
df['proportion'] = df['counts'].div(df['trial_num'].map(s))
```

---

```
print (df)
  trial_num    area  counts  proportion
0         1   first      10    0.285714
1         1  second      25    0.714286
2         2   first      36    0.947368
3         2  second       2    0.052632
4         3   first      70    0.875000
5         3  second      10    0.125000
```